# MYSQL Buscar fechas y excluir aquellas entre Viernes 17:00 y Domingo 17:00

Tags: php, mysql, sql

He buscado tanto en los foros en español y en inglés, en las referencias de W3School y no puedo resolverlo.

El código es en PHP y utilizo MYSQL.
Tengo que hacer un SELECT de fechas en los últimos 3 meses, y debo excluir de los resultados aquellas que vayan entre Viernes a las 17:00hs y Domingo a las 17:00hs.

He intentado varias cosas, y por cansancio he optado por excluir los sábados y domingos por completo pero el código no se comporta tal como debería. No encuentro una función que sea tal como DAYOFWEEK pero que contenga un valor de Hora.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN '$today' AND '$3months') AND (DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) BETWEEN 2 AND 6)
```

He intentado también pero sin éxito:

```
AND (DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) = 6 AND HOUR(timestamp) < 17) AND (DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) = 1 AND HOUR(timestamp) > 17)
```

Lógicamente no funcionó, y ya me he quedado sin ideas.

¡Ayuda por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `DAYOFWEEK()` de MYSQL para obtener el dia de la semana y desecharlo, de hecho puedes leer de eso en [MySQL DAYOFWEEK() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_dayofweek.asp#:~:text=The%20DAYOFWEEK()%20function%20returns,%3DFriday%2C%207%3DSaturday.)

En cuanto a tu consulta para determinar una consulta considerando tres meses al pasado puede usar la funcuion de MYSQL `DATE_SUB()`[MySQL DATE_SUB() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) con la cual restas intervalos de tiempo, ahora si consideras eso ya llevamos 2 de 3 partes de tu codigo y si consideras el operador `BETWEEN` de MYSQL [The SQL BETWEEN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) tu consulta podria quedar mas o menos de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id 
     FROM table 
     WHERE DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) = 6 AND TIME(timestamp) >= "17:00:00" 
     OR DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) = 7 
     OR DAYOFWEEK(timestamp) = 1 AND TIME(timestamp) <= "17:00:00") 
AND DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW();
```